# Why does url.sty appear in 3 different places in the TeX Directory Structure?

Tags: packages, miktex, urls

On my up-to-date MiKTeX system, there is a copy of `url.sty` in three different places in the TDS:

- `texmf\tex\xelatex\xetexurl` (part of MiKTeX package `xetexurl`, packaged on 2007-Sep-05)
- `texmf\tex\latex\url` (part of MiKTeX package `url`, packaged on 2010-Jan-26)
- `texmf\tex\latex\ltxmisc` (part of MiKTeX package `ltxmisc`, packaged on 2012-Dec-20)

The first one (in `xetexurl`) is version 3.1; the other two are version 3.3.

Why does the package exist in 3 different locations?  Given that this is the case, how does the TeX program know which one to use?  It seems that when I run `pdfLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`, it chooses the one from `ltxmisc`, giving log entry

```
Package: url 2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
```

while when running `XeLaTeX` it chooses the one from `xetexurl`, giving this log entry:

```
Package: url 2004/03/15  ver 3.1  Verb mode for urls, etc.
```

Why the discrepancy?

Comment: wouldn't it be better to ask on a miktex forum?  (afaik, christian schenk doesn't read here.)  [note, he may be merely reading, as i originally intended to do, but he has more self control than me (not difficult).]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### `tex/xelatex/xetexurl/url.sty`

The old `url.sty` had used 8-bit characters that break with XeTeX's expectations of input encoded with UTF-8. Thus the file in

```
tex/xelatex/xetexurl/url.sty
```

is a patched version:

```
% url.sty  ver 3.1    15-Mar-2004   Donald Arseneau   ...
...
% Byte codes >= 0x80 replaced by ^^xx sequences - JK, 2006-04-07
```

Since version 3.3 of `url.sty` this is fixed:

```
% ver 3.3 April 2006:
% Fix some encoding bugs and remove 8-bit characters.
```

**Conclusion:** `xetexurl` should be removed:

- Out of date.
- The reason for the patch is gone.
- The patch is a violation of LPPL (LaTeX Project Public License) that requires the renaming of the file without agreement of the author.

### `TDS:tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty` and `TDS:tex/latex/url/url.sty`

The TDS (see ["A Directory Structure for TeX Files"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/tds/tds.pdf)) requires that all file names inside `tex/latex//` and `tex/generic//` are unique (see section "2.4 Duplicate filenames"). (The file in `tex/xelatex` does not clash, because it uses a differnt format directory.)

The reason for the constraint for uniqueness is that it is not defined, which file a TeX engine might find and use.

Therefore one of the two files has to be removed. TeX Live uses `TDS:tex/latex/url/url.sty`. Thus my suggestion would be to remove `TDS:tex/latex/ltxmisc/url.sty`.

**Update 1:** I have made a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2268/), tracker id is 2268.

**Update 2:** Christian Schenk has now fixed the issue by removing the wrong/misplaced versions.

Comment: As far as I know, the LPPL doesn't require a name change (although it's recommended).

Comment: @egreg The file is modified and distributed, thus the conditions of (6) apply. (6a) is violated, because the `\ProvidesPackage` statement does not clearly indicate the change.

Comment: This is different from not renaming the file.

Comment: Thanks.  After updating the packages, I had to "synchronize" the Package Manager so that it wouldn't keep looking for `xetexurl`.