# XeLaTeX and MiKTeX url package problems

Tags: packages, miktex, urls

I have experienced this problem every single time I have tried to compile using XeLaTeX with MiKTeX 2.9 on my windows 7 64-bit machine. I haven't been able to find a solution to my problem anywhere so I am just going to describe it the best I can here with the hope that someone will know what to do.

When I try to typeset using XeLaTeX, I get the following pop up:

The required file

```
tex\xelatex\xetexurl\url.sty
```

is missing. It is a part of the following package:

```
xetexurl
```

I then have to install the package from a random package repository. The file is typeset correctly. I then make some edits and need to typeset the file again. I get the same pop up. Interestingly, at the bottom of the pop up, I have the box checked that states: "Always show this dialog before installing packages." I finally decided to uncheck that box and something interesting happened: I could not typeset a document again using XeLaTeX; the "Process crashed" every single time. I changed my MiKTeX settings to have the program always ask me first and I can now typeset documents again using XeLaTeX, but the pop up always shows up. I thought this question was similar: [Why does url.sty appear in 3 different places in the TeX Directory Structure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116815/why-does-url-sty-appear-in-3-different-places-in-the-tex-directory-structure)

But it has not really helped. I wonder if I am not alone with this issue. It has started to become a real nuisance. Any ideas as to what I can do to avoid having to install this package every single time when typesetting?

Comment: According to the linked question, this should be fixed. That suggests your MiKTeX system is out-of-date. Have you synch the package database in both 'normal' and 'Admin' modes?

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you so much -- synchronizing the package database in both modes fixed the problem!

Comment: In that case, I'll mark as a dupe of the older one: the issue is the same.